# current-active-maps shortens map entries

Tags: keymap, scratch-buffer

I try to print all key bindings in the current buffer using

```
(current-active-maps)
```

In the message buffer, the entries are not fully printed & are replaced by

```
....
```

after a level.
Like this,

```
((keymap (46 . tern-ac-dot-complete) (3 keymap (4 . tern-get-docs) (3 . tern-get-type) (18 . tern-rename-variable)) (27 keymap (44 . tern-pop-find-definition)
 (67108910 . tern-find-definition-by-name) (46 . tern-find-definition))) (keymap (menu-bar keymap (Hide/Show menu-item "Hide/Show" ...)) (S-mouse-2 . hs-
mouse-toggle-hiding) (3 keymap (64 keymap ... ... ... ... ...)))
```

and also, the print format is ugly. How to pretty print the list?
I can do list traversing and print it, but looking at the depth of output string, i am keen on avoiding it.

Comment: @kaushalmodi: Yes, the underlying question is about seeing all of the data (expanding the `...`). Only the proximate question is about that data being key bindings. The accepted answer responds to the proximate question and says nothing about the underlying one. Whether the question should be closed as a dup is judgment call. I voted yes, for now, but the OP's problem is apparently solved with the accepted answer, which does not address the full question. Maybe the question should be edited to ask only about showing all of the key bindings and to not mention filling the ellipses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see a pretty printed version of the result of `(current-active-maps)`, you can use `M-x describe-bindings` (or)

```
C-h b
```